# Spawning child processes from root using runuser command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, privilege-escalation, system-compromise, node.js

I am working as an intern for an online coding platform startup (similar to LeetCode or HackerRank).

The backend is written in Nodejs. Instead of running the code in a sandbox of some sort, the lead dev decided to execute the submitted code using a child process spawned from the main process, which is serving the web pages' contents.

The main process "has to" be run with root privilege (I don't know why because I don't have permission to view the whole project yet). Therefore, all child processes spawned for running the submitted code are all running with "root privilege".

The code in the main process looks something similar to the snippet below:

```
const exeCode = async (fileNameThatContainsTheSubmittedCode) => {

// Everything in the exec() parenthesis will be interpreted by sh
    const { result, } = await exec(`python3 ${fileNameThatContainsTheSubmittedCode}`);

    return result;
};
```

I informed the team about the potential problems of such design during the meeting and they have implemented some changes.

They came up with something in the main process similar to the code below:

```
const exeCode = async (fileNameThatContainsTheSubmittedCode) => {

// Everything in the exec() parenthesis will be interpreted by sh
    const { result, } = await exec(`runuser -l unprivilegedUser -c "python3 ${fileNameThatContainsTheSubmittedCode}"`);

    return result;
};
```

They created an unprivileged user on our ubuntu server and run the "submitted code" as that user via the `runuser` command.

The "unprivileged user" is not in the  `sudo` group nor the `sudoer` file and doesn't have the access to the folder where the source code of our main process is stored; apart from that, the so-called "unprivileged user" still has read/write/execute access just like any other normal users created via `adduser`.

I know this is a very hacky way that will only fend of basic attempts, and privilege escalation is very possible.

> But my question is that does spawning child processes with `runuser` offer at least some level of protection when the main process is still running as `root`? Or it just a false sense of security?

> Let's assume that the source code of the main process is secure and the code that is used to spawn the child processes won't be modified.

Comment: Just the fact that you don't use any kind of sandbox or VM makes me want to confidently bet money that your system will get compromised in less than a year. Oh, and mine bitcoin - a whole lot of it.

Comment: It's my first few days here. They told me that no one has ever mentioned it before and stuff were all running as root so I was like tf?  They made the changes as above and I was still like tf? That's why I'm here asking to see if there is anyone who can prove my point of this implementation doesn't really help mitigate the actual threat.

Comment: We can't "prove" anything without the code. But the fact that a bunch of professionals had one glance at the system you described and all said "This will end in disaster" *could* be an indicator.